# ASP.NET membership - Redirect users with unpaid invoice

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm working on a custom implementation of ASP.NET membership, which uses my own database tables. Everything works as it should, but I need to redirect customers, which have not paid their invoice, to a payment page. This should not only happen on login, but also for users which already are logged in, so if an invoice is registered as "not paid" while the user is logged in, then the user must be redirected to the payment page, the next time they load a page.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar to this using a HttpModule. What you want to do is handle the PreRequest event and if they are authenticated and if so make your unpaid invoice check and redirect as necessary.

e.g.

```
protected void OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Path != "/UnPaid.aspx" && HttpContext.Current.User != null)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // You don't want to make this check for every resource type
                bool isPage = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.EndsWith(".aspx") || HttpContext.Current.Request.Path == "/";
                if (isPage)
                {
                    bool isPaid = false; // Make isPaid check here
                    if (!isPaid)
                    {
                        // Optional pass ina return url for after the invoice is paid
                        string returnUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl, HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentEncoding);

                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(string.Concat("/UnPaid.aspx?ReturnUrl=", returnUrl), true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't let the membership provider know this information. It is job of your application to know this, not your security model. It *may* be as simple as adding/removing a role, but that's not ideal either.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that on `global.asax` using the `Application_AuthenticateRequest`

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       string cTheFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;

       if(!cTheFile.EndsWith("ThePaymentPage.aspx"))
       {           
          if(HttpContext.Current.User != null 
             && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity != null 
              && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
          {
              // check here if need to redirect or not.
              if(NeedPayment())
              {
                HttpContext.Current.Responce.Redirect("ThePaymentPage.aspx");
              }
          }
        }
}
```

This is called on every page, so maybe you can add some more checks and make it real fast. Other checks can be if the page ends on `.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

How about having inheritance.
You can "inject" a BasePage between Page class and your ASPX code behind class.
This way, you will have access to your business logic classes and then you can decide, on each request, where the user should be re-directed.

Me too agree on the point that this logic should be handled by your applications business logic instead of the security model.

Hope this helps.